# How to configure access throttling for all wso2 data services?

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server

How to configure same access throttling configuration for data services?

We have lots of data services, it is difficult to configure one by one.

BR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer the document on [1] which explains how to configure access throttling on WSO2 DSS.

[1]. http://docs.wso2.org/display/DSS311/Access+Throttling

Thank You,
Dharshana.